# Idiom or phrase to denote unfair use of someone who is nice

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-usage

I am looking for an idiom or a phrase to denote the situation where someone is unfairly taken advantage of (Ex: Gets a lot of work dumped on his lap on a Friday evening like Harold in Harold and Kumar series) because that someone is nice and does not say no. In my mother tongue there is a usage for this; when translated verbatim it sounds like this "keep on digging where it is wet" - is there something similar in English?

Comment: The usual expression is **take advantage of**. It doesn't need to carry the sense of exploitation / manipulation, but very often does.

Comment: also, this type of person is often a *"yes" man*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth does take advantage of provide enough negative connotations here - its surprising that there are no common idioms..

Comment: In context, certainly. So does the slang 'take someone for a mug'. If someone is trying to exploit _you_, the usual comeback is 'What did your last slave die of?'

Answer (score 2):

You could say that others "run rough-shod," over the nice guy, or, *bulldoze* him - although the latter usually refers to convincing the subordinate that it was their responsibility in the first place.

Comment: Hey there, Old Bag! +1